# How to extract text from the PDF document?

Tags: php, pdf, text, unicode

How to extract text from the PDF document *using PHP*?

(I can't use other tools, I don't have root access)

I've found some functions working for plain text, but they don't handle well Unicode characters:

http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/zend-lucene-and-pdf-documents-part-2-pdf-data-extraction-437.html

Comment: link doesn't work! please rectify!

Comment: Don't see why this question is considered off-topic as it is very useful, even if it may attract 'opinionated' answers, it is always better to see different points of views. Has a lot of hits too.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Download  the **class.pdf2text.php** @ [https://pastebin.com/dvwySU1a](http://pastebin.com/dvwySU1a) or https://webcheatsheet.com/php/scripts/pdf2text.zip

Code:

```
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('filename.pdf'); 
$a->decodePDF();
echo $a->output();
```

---

- `class.pdf2text.php` [Project Home](https://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php)
- `pdf2textclass` doesn't work with all the PDF's I've tested, If it doesn't work for you, try [PDF Parser](https://www.pdfparser.org/demo)

Comment: if here is any table in pdf file then it doesn't show it. i want to extract as it is displaying in pdf also text of scanned image attached with pdf. any solution for that??

Comment: Thanks a lot... That class is very useful. In this I want just a url from pdf. Any way to find that...?

Comment: The class includes an output buffer flush that can cause 'headers already sent' errors. Seemingly no ill-effects if you disable it (for any reasonable size of document).

Comment: @CJRamki Extract the text and then use a regex to match urls.

Comment: Yes, class is not working for all. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: You may want to try http://pdfparser.org/ .

Comment: Pastebin link is not working, here is the direct link of the project owner https://webcheatsheet.com/php/scripts/pdf2text.zip

Comment: @doraemon Pastebin link is working normally for me.

Comment: @PedroLobito They might have a country restriction, I see "This site can’t be reached" error on Chrome. I tried a proxy server and it worked.

Comment: @doraemon I've update the answer, tks