# Upload PDF file and Convert it to text

Tags: php, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract text from the PDF document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999889/how-to-extract-text-from-the-pdf-document)

im a newbie to php. I am working on file. Thing is, I know the way to upload pdf file and also have a code to convert it to text.

The thing is i want to link them i.e., when i upload a pdf file it should take the file uploaded as input and generate corresponding converted text file. can any one explain the way or provide any useful links for this problem

Comment: Dont you already have the code to convert it to text? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: So if you know how to upload the file, and you have the code to convert it to text ... merge them and use the uploaded file in your conversion code ..

Comment: @Anonymous Yeah. I do have the code. But its too long to paste i guess. About 300 lines

Comment: @webnoob Yes, thats what my question says. I need help in merging both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Theres a free script here for that if interested.

[PHP Extract from PDF](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6155-PHP-Extract-text-from-PDF-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

The site http://php.net/

should be your friend. Like I understand you need to create a file with text content.
The easiest function for this task is `file_put_contents`.
Also look at the other file functions. http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: This is totally irrelevant to OP's request. It's almost a spam comment. file_put_contents saves a file. Has nothing to do with PDF files.