# Is there a way to process PDF files as text files in PHP?

Tags: php, csv, pdf

My company receives coupons codes from another company and I need to process them to use them in my company's website. The problem is that they send me a PDF file with the codes, and *they say* their system can only export them in PDF. Strange.

I've tried several times to let them know that I need those coupons in plain text separated by something (a.k.a CSV) and they doesn't take any notice of that.

My website is written in PHP, and uses MySQL. I would like to offer a way to upload that coupons file and add those to the database. It would be easy considering it is a CSV file but it's not.

Is there any way I can programatically -not manually- process PDF files as text files? or, any workaround for this situation?

Comment: Can you select and copy the text in a viewer like Adobe Reader correctly?

Comment: I need to do it programatically, not manually.

Comment: Yes, but the question is if Adobe Reader for example can parse it. I think then is an easier implementation possible.

Comment: I need to let my website upload a PDF or something, PHP process it, and add those codes to my database.

Comment: @whitenoisedb I think a better question is if the PDF is actual text, instead of just an image.

Comment: PDF contains those coupons in text I think. I can select them.

Comment: Sorry. I hadn't understand your first question. So yes, I can select copy and paste. It's text.

Comment: You can do this with iText in Java probably. PHP, don't know.

Comment: Try these:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999889/how-to-extract-text-from-the-pdf-document
http://www.pdfparser.org/

Answer (score 1):

I have found pdf2text to have worked well for quite some time.

Will not work with image (TIFF) PDF.  will work with text searchable PDF.

```
  include('/home/user/php/class.pdf2text.php');
  $p2t = new PDF2Text();
  $p2t ->setFilename($pdf);
  $p2t ->decodePDF();
  $data = $p2t ->output();
  $pos = strpos($data,$search);
  if (pos){...}
```

### Source:

```
<?php

class PDF2Text {
        // Some settings
        var $multibyte = 4; // Use setUnicode(TRUE|FALSE)
        var $convertquotes = ENT_QUOTES; // ENT_COMPAT (double-quotes), ENT_QUOTES (Both), ENT_NOQUOTES (None)
        var $showprogress = true; // TRUE if you have problems with time-out

        // Variables
        var $filename = '';
        var $decodedtext = '';

        function setFilename($filename) {
                // Reset
                $this->decodedtext = '';
                $this->filename = $filename;
        }

        function output($echo = false) {
                if($echo) echo $this->decodedtext;
                else return $this->decodedtext;
        }

        function setUnicode($input) {
                // 4 for unicode. But 2 should work in most cases just fine
                if($input == true) $this->multibyte = 4;
                else $this->multibyte = 2;
        }

        function decodePDF() {
                // Read the data from pdf file
                $infile = @file_get_contents($this->filename, FILE_BINARY);
                if (empty($infile))
                        return "";

                // Get all text data.
                $transformations = array();
                $texts = array();

                // Get the list of all objects.
                preg_match_all("#obj[\n|\r](.*)endobj[\n|\r]#ismU", $infile . "endobj\r", $objects);
                $objects = @$objects[1];

                // Select objects with streams.
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($objects); $i++) {
                        $currentObject = $objects[$i];

                        // Prevent time-out
                        @set_time_limit ();
                        if($this->showprogress) {
//                              echo ". ";
                                flush(); ob_flush();
                        }

                        // Check if an object includes data stream.
                        if (preg_match("#stream[\n|\r](.*)endstream[\n|\r]#ismU", $currentObject . "endstream\r", $stream )) {
                                $stream = ltrim($stream[1]);
                                // Check object parameters and look for text data.
                                $options = $this->getObjectOptions($currentObject);

                                if (!(empty($options["Length1"]) && empty($options["Type"]) && empty($options["Subtype"])) )
//                              if ( $options["Image"] && $options["Subtype"] )
//                              if (!(empty($options["Length1"]) &&  empty($options["Subtype"])) )
                                        continue;

                                // Hack, length doesnt always seem to be correct
                                unset($options["Length"]);

                                // So, we have text data. Decode it.
                                $data = $this->getDecodedStream($stream, $options);

                                if (strlen($data)) {
                        if (preg_match_all("#BT[\n|\r](.*)ET[\n|\r]#ismU", $data . "ET\r", $textContainers)) {
                                                $textContainers = @$textContainers[1];
                                                $this->getDirtyTexts($texts, $textContainers);
                                        } else
                                                $this->getCharTransformations($transformations, $data);
                                }
                        }
                }

                // Analyze text blocks taking into account character transformations and return results.
                $this->decodedtext = $this->getTextUsingTransformations($texts, $transformations);
        }


        function decodeAsciiHex($input) {
                $output = "";

                $isOdd = true;
                $isComment = false;

                for($i = 0, $codeHigh = -1; $i < strlen($input) && $input[$i] != '>'; $i++) {
                        $c = $input[$i];

                        if($isComment) {
                                if ($c == '\r' || $c == '\n')
                                        $isComment = false;
                                continue;
                        }

                        switch($c) {
                                case '\0': case '\t': case '\r': case '\f': case '\n': case ' ': break;
                                case '%':
                                        $isComment = true;
                                break;

                                default:
                                        $code = hexdec($c);
                                        if($code === 0 && $c != '0')
                                                return "";

                                        if($isOdd)
                                                $codeHigh = $code;
                                        else
                                                $output .= chr($codeHigh * 16 + $code);

                                        $isOdd = !$isOdd;
                                break;
                        }
                }

                if($input[$i] != '>')
                        return "";

                if($isOdd)
                        $output .= chr($codeHigh * 16);

                return $output;
        }

        function decodeAscii85($input) {
                $output = "";

                $isComment = false;
                $ords = array();

                for($i = 0, $state = 0; $i < strlen($input) && $input[$i] != '~'; $i++) {
                        $c = $input[$i];

                        if($isComment) {
                                if ($c == '\r' || $c == '\n')
                                        $isComment = false;
                                continue;
                        }

                        if ($c == '\0' || $c == '\t' || $c == '\r' || $c == '\f' || $c == '\n' || $c == ' ')
                                continue;
                        if ($c == '%') {
                                $isComment = true;
                                continue;
                        }
                        if ($c == 'z' && $state === 0) {
                                $output .= str_repeat(chr(0), 4);
                                continue;
                        }
                        if ($c < '!' || $c > 'u')
                                return "";

                        $code = ord($input[$i]) & 0xff;
                        $ords[$state++] = $code - ord('!');

                        if ($state == 5) {
                                $state = 0;
                                for ($sum = 0, $j = 0; $j < 5; $j++)
                                        $sum = $sum * 85 + $ords[$j];
                                for ($j = 3; $j >= 0; $j--)
                                        $output .= chr($sum >> ($j * 8));
                        }
                }
                if ($state === 1)
                        return "";
                elseif ($state > 1) {
                        for ($i = 0, $sum = 0; $i < $state; $i++)
                                $sum += ($ords[$i] + ($i == $state - 1)) * pow(85, 4 - $i);
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $state - 1; $i++) {
                                try {
                                        if(false == ($o = chr($sum >> ((3 - $i) * 8)))) {
                                                throw new Exception('Error');
                                        }
                                        $output .= $o;
                                } catch (Exception $e) { /*Dont do anything*/ }
                        }
                }

                return $output;
        }

        function decodeFlate($data) {
                return @gzuncompress($data);
        }

        function getObjectOptions($object) {
                $options = array();

                if (preg_match("#<<(.*)>>#ismU", $object, $options)) {
                        $options = explode("/", $options[1]);
                        @array_shift($options);

                        $o = array();
                        for ($j = 0; $j < @count($options); $j++) {
                                $options[$j] = preg_replace("#\s+#", " ", trim($options[$j]));
                                if (strpos($options[$j], " ") !== false) {
                                        $parts = explode(" ", $options[$j]);
                                        $o[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
                                } else
                                        $o[$options[$j]] = true;
                        }
                        $options = $o;
                        unset($o);
                }

                return $options;
        }

        function getDecodedStream($stream, $options) {
                $data = "";
                if (empty($options["Filter"]))
                        $data = $stream;
                else {
                        $length = !empty($options["Length"]) ? $options["Length"] : strlen($stream);
                        $_stream = substr($stream, 0, $length);

                        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
                                if ($key == "ASCIIHexDecode")
                                        $_stream = $this->decodeAsciiHex($_stream);
                                elseif ($key == "ASCII85Decode")
                                        $_stream = $this->decodeAscii85($_stream);
                                elseif ($key == "FlateDecode")
                                        $_stream = $this->decodeFlate($_stream);
                                elseif ($key == "Crypt") { // TO DO
                                }
                        }
                        $data = $_stream;
                }
                return $data;
        }

        function getDirtyTexts(&$texts, $textContainers) {
                for ($j = 0; $j < count($textContainers); $j++) {
                        if (preg_match_all("#\[(.*)\]\s*TJ[\n|\r]#ismU", $textContainers[$j], $parts))
                                $texts = array_merge($texts, array(@implode('', $parts[1])));
                        elseif (preg_match_all("#T[d|w|m|f]\s*(\(.*\))\s*Tj[\n|\r]#ismU", $textContainers[$j], $parts))
                                $texts = array_merge($texts, array(@implode('', $parts[1])));
                        elseif (preg_match_all("#T[d|w|m|f]\s*(\[.*\])\s*Tj[\n|\r]#ismU", $textContainers[$j], $parts))
                                $texts = array_merge($texts, array(@implode('', $parts[1])));
                }

        }

        function getCharTransformations(&$transformations, $stream) {
                preg_match_all("#([0-9]+)\s+beginbfchar(.*)endbfchar#ismU", $stream, $chars, PREG_SET_ORDER);
                preg_match_all("#([0-9]+)\s+beginbfrange(.*)endbfrange#ismU", $stream, $ranges, PREG_SET_ORDER);

                for ($j = 0; $j < count($chars); $j++) {
                        $count = $chars[$j][1];
                        $current = explode("\n", trim($chars[$j][2]));
                        for ($k = 0; $k < $count && $k < count($current); $k++) {
                                if (preg_match("#<([0-9a-f]{2,4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4,512})>#is", trim($current[$k]), $map))
                                        $transformations[str_pad($map[1], 4, "0")] = $map[2];
                        }
                }
                for ($j = 0; $j < count($ranges); $j++) {
                        $count = $ranges[$j][1];
                        $current = explode("\n", trim($ranges[$j][2]));
                        for ($k = 0; $k < $count && $k < count($current); $k++) {
                                if (preg_match("#<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4})>#is", trim($current[$k]), $map)) {
                                        $from = hexdec($map[1]);
                                        $to = hexdec($map[2]);
                                        $_from = hexdec($map[3]);

                                        for ($m = $from, $n = 0; $m <= $to; $m++, $n++)
                                                $transformations[sprintf("%04X", $m)] = sprintf("%04X", $_from + $n);
                                } elseif (preg_match("#<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+\[(.*)\]#ismU", trim($current[$k]), $map)) {
                                        $from = hexdec($map[1]);
                                        $to = hexdec($map[2]);
                                        $parts = preg_split("#\s+#", trim($map[3]));

                                        for ($m = $from, $n = 0; $m <= $to && $n < count($parts); $m++, $n++)
                                                $transformations[sprintf("%04X", $m)] = sprintf("%04X", hexdec($parts[$n]));
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        function getTextUsingTransformations($texts, $transformations) {
                $document = "";
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($texts); $i++) {
                        $isHex = false;
                        $isPlain = false;

                        $hex = "";
                        $plain = "";
                        for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($texts[$i]); $j++) {
                                $c = $texts[$i][$j];
                                switch($c) {
                                        case "<":
                                                $hex = "";
                                                $isHex = true;
                        $isPlain = false;
                                        break;
                                        case ">":
                                                $hexs = str_split($hex, $this->multibyte); // 2 or 4 (UTF8 or ISO)
                                                for ($k = 0; $k < count($hexs); $k++) {

                                                        $chex = str_pad($hexs[$k], 4, "0"); // Add tailing zero
                                                        if (isset($transformations[$chex]))
                                                                $chex = $transformations[$chex];
                                                        $document .= html_entity_decode("&#x".$chex.";");
                                                }
                                                $isHex = false;
                                        break;
                                        case "(":
                                                $plain = "";
                                                $isPlain = true;
                        $isHex = false;
                                        break;
                                        case ")":
                                                $document .= $plain;
                                                $isPlain = false;
                                        break;
                                        case "\\":
                                                $c2 = $texts[$i][$j + 1];
                                                if (in_array($c2, array("\\", "(", ")"))) $plain .= $c2;
                                                elseif ($c2 == "n") $plain .= '\n';
                                                elseif ($c2 == "r") $plain .= '\r';
                                                elseif ($c2 == "t") $plain .= '\t';
                                                elseif ($c2 == "b") $plain .= '\b';
                                                elseif ($c2 == "f") $plain .= '\f';
                                                elseif ($c2 >= '0' && $c2 <= '9') {
                                                        $oct = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", substr($texts[$i], $j + 1, 3));
                                                        $j += strlen($oct) - 1;
                                                        $plain .= html_entity_decode("&#".octdec($oct).";", $this->convertquotes);
                                                }
                                                $j++;
                                        break;

                                        default:
                                                if ($isHex)
                                                        $hex .= $c;
                                                elseif ($isPlain)
                                                        $plain .= $c;
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                        $document .= "\n";
                }

                return $document;
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: only runs for some files