# Extracting text from .doc/.pdf file in my HTML

Tags: html

I researched this topic, but the answers I found included creating an iframe and such. I wanted to know whether it is possible to not contain the text I want to display not in my  but in a separate .doc or .pdf file and only extract the text within it? 
If that seems like a really bad practice in terms that it would most likely increase my page load time. Are there any other techniques that I can employ to display large amount of text on my website?

Comment: Do you want to show the contents of your doc or pdf to the visitors' of your page or just extract contents and use it for something else?

Comment: you can have a look at [a](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/6155-PHP-Extract-text-from-PDF-files.html) and [b](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7001377/3697102)

Comment: Yeah I think thats what I was looking for. I don't know for sure. But I'll definitely check it out and let you guys know. Cheers.

Comment: let me know so that I can post the answer for others who visits this question.