# How to check pdf is exist or same 80% in mysql?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, pdf, compare

How to check pdf is exist or same 80% in mysql? 
User want to upload pdf. 
But problem is reup. 
I think covert pdf to binary 
=> I will have a string "X"(binary of that pdf) to save in mysql. 
=> Select like %(splice (1/3 length(X) -> 2/3 length(X)). 
maybe do it?
im using laravel
thank for reading

Comment: So you are asking to check if two PDF files are similar for atleast 80%?  i think that the best method is the generate a checksum out off 80% from that file and compare those

Comment: What does "same" mean? Same text? Same binary data? If I take 80% off a PDF and replace the rest with zeroes, it will probably not be readable at all. If I take 80% of the text from a PDF and copy it into a different document and save it as PDF, it will have a negligible binary overlap with the original (because PDF files typically use zip-encoded chunks, which will vary widely even with substantial duplicate contents)

Comment: Finally, two PDFs which render the exact same pixels may be almost completely different, because PDF is a representation format, and you can replace all text with images of its characters and visually, nobody will know the difference.

Comment: MySQL is almost certainly the wrong tool for this.  I can give you 2 PDFs with the *exact same* content but different file data just by rearranging the table of contents.

Answer (score 3):

**This cannot be done reasonably in MySQL**. Since you are also using a PHP environment, it may be possible to perform via PHP, but to achieve a general solution you will need substantial effort.

PDF files are [composed of (possibly compressed) streams of images and text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#File_structure). Several [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999889/how-to-extract-text-from-the-pdf-document) can attempt to extract the text, and will work reasonably well if the PDF was generated in a straightforward way; however, they will typically fail if some text was rendered as images of its characters, or if other ofuscation has been applied. In those cases, you will need to use [OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract%20Tesseract%20OCR) to generate the actual text as it is seen when the PDF is displayed. Note also that tables and images are out-of-scope for these tools.

Once you have two text files, finding overlaps becomes much easier, although there are several techniques. "Same 80%" can be interpreted in several ways, but let us assume that copying a contiguous 79% of the text from a file and saving it again should not trigger alarms, while copying 81% of that same text should trigger them. Any [diff](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xdiff.php) tool can provide information on duplicate chunks, and may be enough for your purposes. A more sophisticated approach, which however does not provide exact percentages, is to use the [normalized compression distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_compression_distance).