# Extract text from PDF with PDF2Text (PHP)

Tags: php, pdf, web-scraping, pdftotext

I'm trying to extract the text from several PDF's, using the library class.pdf2text.php

However, the extracted content is:

```
5(68/7$76 $%62/876 ,, 0LWMD L 4XDUW GH 0DUDWy (V /ORPEDUGV   0HQRUV ,, 0LWMD L 4XDUW GH 0DUDWy (V /ORPEDUGV   0HQRUV &XUVD SRSXODU GRPLQJR  GH GLFLHPEUH GH  $MXQWDPHQW GH 6DQWDQ\t 'RUVDO1RP L /OLQDWJHV $Q\ QD[ &OXE&LXWDW 7B2ILFLDO PNP 3RV&DW 7B5HDO 3RV 5HDO  'DQL 'H\D 5H\QHV  6RQ 2OLYD   60     0DUF &HUYDQWHV 2EUDGRU    60     'DYLG $UWLJXHV -LDQX    60     (PPD &HUYDQWHV 2EUDGRU    ) 6)     /OLEHUWDW &OHU 2UWHJD    ) 6)    3iJLQD  GH  ZZZHOLWHFKLSQHW LQIR#HOLWHFKLSQHW 7(/
```

The code is:

```
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename ( $pdfURL );
$a->decodePDF();
echo $a->output();
```

Comment: So which is your problem exactly ?

Comment: I want to extract the decoded text, not strange characters.

Comment: did you include class?
`include('class.pdf2text.php');`

Comment: Yes, I can extract the content from other PDFs, but with some PDFs I get strange characters. I suppose the text is encoded.

Comment: Possible duplicate, see this answer : [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999889/how-to-extract-text-from-the-pdf-document)

Comment: I've already read it before answering again. The code in this post is the same.

Comment: Are you sure is not protect file?

Comment: How could I know it?

Comment: Guide for official site: [LINK](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/protected-view-feature-pdfs-windows.html)

Comment: The PDF is online, not locally:
http://www.elitechip.net/system/public/download/2d7f6fc561160ff14e5c580f850bc031.pdf

Comment: Have you tried local path for see if work?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it too.

Comment: So it's simple "limit" of that class, try to use : http://pdfparser.org/

Comment: It returns NULL. However, with other PDFs, PHP2Text and PDFParser libraries works fine, and I can extract all text.

Comment: Can you link that specific PDF here? Without looking at it, I think we won't get any idea.

Comment: http://www.elitechip.net/system/public/download/2d7f6fc561160ff14e5c580f850bc031.pdf